# Electron - Cannot use puppeteer inside worker thread

Tags: electron, puppeteer, electron-builder

I would like to use puppeteer inside worker threads in my electron app. When building the bundle, I use extraFiles to copy worker code to Resources/bin. But unfortunately, it throws exception: "Cannot find module puppeteer" after running. What I had already tried:

- Import puppeteer normally:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

- Import puppeteer in app.asar.unpack:

```
const puppeteerPath = path.resolve(
  process.resourcesPath,
  'app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/puppeteer/index.js'
);
const puppeteer = require(`${puppeteerPath}`);
```

- Import puppeteer in app.asar:

```
const puppeteerPath = path.resolve(
  process.resourcesPath,
  'app.asar/node_modules/puppeteer/index.js'
);
const puppeteer = require(`${puppeteerPath}`);
```

Here is the repo which reproduce my case: https://github.com/alfredalfie123/test_worker

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is this your repo where you are using puppeteer?

Comment: @tpikachu yes it is. I fork from electron-react-boilerplate and edit some code to demonstrate what I did

Comment: i can't see puppeteer dependency at package.json

Comment: @tpikachu it's included in app/package.json, following this comment: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/1487

Comment: well? why are you not including this at root `package.json`?

Comment: The electron-builder will consider the package.json to packing the node_modules

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy all puppetter related deps to asar.unpack:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18540#issuecomment-660679649